# How to determine missing windows service dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

We have a C# windows service that is failing to start up on a server reboot.  If we connect up to the server and manually start the service it starts and runs without problems.

I understand that this is probably due to the service being dependent on a windows service that hasn't started up yet.  I'd like to determine which services could be required.  I can ascertain which namespaces the service dependent on but how do I know which windows services are required?

Is there a way to identify required services, from within Visual Studio perhaps?

Note: I have professional edition of VS 2019 so I can't create dependancy graphs etc...

EDITS:
We're using NLog for logging throughout the app but nothing gets logged.

We get a service start timeout after 30s and nothing other than that logged in the eventviewer.

Comment: Look into Windows Log on the server. It should spit out error message and stack trace.

Comment: Add error logging? Nine out of ten times it's networking, so add a dependency on `tcpip` and you're golden...

Comment: Will add some detail to the question...

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a delayed start? It would probably give it a better chance at starting while you work on figuring out the root cause. (And just beware, delayed start doesn't mean "will always start", it just means it will be delayed a bit, which if not enough, would still have it crashing)

Comment: Yeah, have tried delayed start and it helps but not 100% of time

Comment: No, it won't. You still need to figure out the dependency. Have you tried writing a simple text-based "log" at the start of the program to see if that works? ie. the first line of your executable code could be something like `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\myservice.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());`, does that file get created?

Comment: I've set NLOG to trace logging which should effectively provide the same logging (the service start has nlog trace logging).  But I've added the suggested dependency to tcpip and restarted 3 times with success each time so thus far I can't recreate the problem.  Will play with removing the tcpip dependency and do some more testing